# how to get field values from database in template page Advanced Custom Fields - wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have installed an Advanced Custom Fields plugin to upload audio and image files in post. Each post contains 5 fields

**New Post with custom fields**
[image: New Post with custom fields]

I can able to publish the post, but i dont know how to retrieve each field in a wordpress template page

**Post fields**
[image: Post fields]

Answer (score 1):

Just call this function with name of field in your template file

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
        // Display post
        if ( have_posts() ):?> 
      <?php echo  the_field('slider_name');?>
     <?php echo   the_field('slider_description');

 endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Currently, your answer is flagged "low quality" and might get removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_field('main_content_heading'); ?></h1>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Within the loop, use the_field method to output the custom field.

See here for more details: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/